# How should I pretreat painted plasterboard before gluing fiber cement sheet over it

Tags: tiling, adhesive

I'm going to glue (and nail) cement tile underlay sheet to a painted plasterboard wall.

The paint seems to have decent adherence, should I do anything before gluing?

Comment: I'm thinking of doing something similar. Can you recommend which kind of adhesive to use?

Answer (score 1):

I'd sand it lightly and wash it thoroughly afterwards to get any particles off, you'll get better and longer-lasting adherence.